# qtconfig fonts list on linux

Tags: linux, qt, fonts

I've built qt 4.7.4 on ubuntu and my application fonts look terrible. I used qtconfig to try and make the font more pleasing to the eye, but most look really bad (not aliased, and the list of fonts appears incomplete; e.g the clearlooks font in gnome uses "sans", but this doesn't appear in the list of available fonts in qtconfig).

However, if I install qtconfig-qt4 using aptitude, the fonts rendered in that application look great and there are loads more fonts available. The settings however are not applied to my qt applications.

I have no idea where qtconfig is picking up the font settings it makes available nor where it is saving the settings. The qt docs don't seem to help as far as I can see.

If someone could help me with either setting up the qtconfig in my install (maybe I need to configure with some different options - I used -debug-and-release -fast -qt-libtiff -no-webkit ?) or getting my apps to pick up the qtconfig-qt4 settings I would be most grateful! I would prefer the former!

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue where qtconfig doesn't seem to be picking up the system fonts. Found some settings in kubuntu under appearance - fonts where I changed "use anti-aliasing" to enabled (from system) and then when configured I enabled "use sub-pixel rendering".

I think this gets stored in a file `~/.fonts.conf`.

Still haven't figured out how to get all the fonts to appear in qtconfig though.